# Making a calendar c++ (Beginner)

Tags: c++

I am making a calendar, and I have managed to show the calendar's headers, but I don't know how to make the body or the actual dates/numbers for the months be aligned with each month and how to make them show. The plan is for the user to input the year they want to see the calendar for. I've already set up a function to get the year the user wishes and checks if it a leap year and also checks the date of the first day of the year.
[image] I am making the calender in that format

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    

    int GetFirstDay(int year);

    void main()
    {
        int year, numdays;
        int month = 1;
        // getting the user to give the year
        cout << "Enter year: ";
        cin >> year;
        cout << "\n\n";

        // getting first day of given year
        int First_Day = GetFirstDay(year);
        while (month <= 12) {
            switch (month) {
            //Body
            case 1:
                numdays = 31;
                cout << "January" << endl;
                cout << "S  M  T  W  T  F  S" << endl;
                cout << "-------------------" << endl << endl;
                break;

            case 2:
                if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)) { numdays = 29; }
                else { numdays = 28; }
                cout << "Febrary" << endl;
                cout << "S  M  T  W  T  F  S" << endl;
                cout << "-------------------" << endl << endl;
                break;

            case 3:
                numdays = 31;
                cout << "March" << endl;
                cout << "S  M  T  W  T  F  S" << endl;
                cout << "-------------------" << endl << endl;
                break;

            case 4:
                numdays = 30;
                cout << "April"<< endl;
                cout << "S  M  T  W  T  F  S" << endl;
                cout << "-------------------" << endl << endl;
                break;

            case 5:
                numdays = 31;
                cout << "May" << endl;
                cout << "S  M  T  W  T  F  S" << endl;
                cout << "-------------------" << endl << endl;
                break;

            case 6:
                numdays = 30;
                cout << "June" << endl;
                cout << "S  M  T  W  T  F  S" << endl;
                cout << "-------------------" << endl << endl;
                break;

            case 7:
                numdays = 31;
                cout << "July" << endl;
                cout << "S  M  T  W  T  F  S" << endl;
                cout << "-------------------" << endl << endl;
                break;

            case 8:
                numdays = 31;
                cout << "August" << endl;
                cout << "S  M  T  W  T  F  S" << endl;
                cout << "-------------------" << endl << endl;
                break;

            case 9:
                numdays = 30;
                cout << "September" << endl;
                cout << "S  M  T  W  T  F  S" << endl;
                cout << "-------------------" << endl << endl;
                break;

            case 10:
                numdays = 31;
                cout << "October" << endl;
                cout << "S  M  T  W  T  F  S" << endl;
                cout << "-------------------" << endl << endl;
                break;

            case 11:
                numdays = 31;
                cout << "November" << endl;
                cout << "S  M  T  W  T  F  S" << endl;
                cout << "-------------------" << endl << endl;
                break;

            case 12:
                numdays = 31;
                cout << "December" << endl;
                cout << "S  M  T  W  T  F  S" << endl;
                cout << "-------------------" << endl << endl;
                break;
            }
            month++;
        }



    }

    int GetFirstDay(int year) {
        int century = (year - 1) / 100;
        int y = (year - 1) % 100;
        int weekday = (((29 - (2 * century) + y + (y / 4) + (century / 4)) % 7) + 7) % 7;
        // 0 would be sunday and 6 would be Saturday
        return weekday;

     }
```

Comment: I assume what you show is the desired output. Please also show the output you achieve and describe the differences, in more detail than "not aligned".

Comment: What [books](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) did you read about C++ and about calendars? Are you allowed to use the [standard `<chrono>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) ? Did you look inside [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) ? Did you compile your C++ code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`? Did you read the documentation of your C++ compiler?

Comment: ... did you use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you'll need a function which tells you which day it is, given day, month and year.

```
Index    Day 
0        Sunday 
1        Monday 
2        Tuesday 
3        Wednesday 
4        Thursday 
5        Friday 
6        Saturday
```

Find the starting day of each month, and print tab spaces accordingly. For example, if starting day is Wednesday, print 3 tab spaces, or any number of spaces according to your formatting. Do this for each month, and you should have your desired alignment

```
//A Function that returns the index of the day of the date - day/month/year 
int dayNumber(int day, int month, int year) 
{ 

    static int t[] = { 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 
                    4, 6, 2, 4 }; 
    year -= month < 3; 
    return ( year + year/4 - year/100 + 
            year/400 + t[month-1] + day) % 7; 
}
```

TIP : Instead of Hardcoding the months, have a function or array which returns the month name as a string, so that you can loop through the 12 months

```
string getMonthName(int monthNumber) 
{ 
    string months[] = {"January", "February", "March", 
                    "April", "May", "June", 
                    "July", "August", "September", 
                    "October", "November", "December"
                    }; 

    return (months[monthNumber]); 
}
```